# My iPhone 4 is not showing me on my text message when I have a message

Tags: iphone

My iPhone is not showing me when I have messages on the Messages app, and is also not ringing when I have text messages even though my settings are set to alert me when I get one.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running on your phone? Can you clarify the settings you currently have to alert you in Notifications for Messages?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the question.

When you say messages are these SMS (green speech bubbles) or iMessage (blue speech bubbles)? Or both? These are both read inside the message app on the iPhone.

If it is the SMS you may have a carrier glitch - if it is the blue you may have an issue with your Apple ID.

If you haven't already - the first port of call for all iPhone troubles is to do a soft reset - this is different to turing off and then on. Hold both the home and power buttons until the phone switches off - **keep holding until the Apple logo appears** and the phone begins to restart.

Also a good idea to close the apps you have running in the background - double click home button and swipe up those you want to close.

Let us know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mesaage is turned off in notifications, my husband had the same problem and that is what fixed his